# Mixed layout types?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a simple app. What's the best way do create GUI like this? How do I mix layouts?

http://s15.postimg.org/iic9v0v97/example.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [TextField](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html), a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)(vertical orientation).

EDIT:
This is a scratch:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="fill_parent"
    android:height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum=100
    orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        android:weight="70"> //70%of the parent width
        <TextField
           android:width="100px"
           android:height="100px"
           alignParentToLeft
           alignParentToTop>
        </TextField>
        <TableLayout
           ...
           align bottom left>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       ...
       android:weight="30"> //30%of the parent layout
     //in this part should be the right column
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I know that, but how do i set screen to parts? Till this time I was creating simply apps with only one layout per activity. Is there such thing as weight in layouts?

Comment: Yes ofc, there is a weight property that u can use for linear layout. I will edit my answer and show you a scratch